# Injecting bean value to attribute using @value not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Suppose I have a bean `abc` with an attribute `xyz` (which has some value), now I have a pojo and need to inject this value to `istrue` attribute :

```
 @Value("#{'{#abc.xyz}'=='lmop' ? false : true'}")
 @Column
 private Boolean istrue;
```

Initialization of `abc` bean happens in starter packages.

Comment: `@Value` is only supported on Spring managed instances. Judging from the fact that there is an `@Column` this isn't Spring managed, but rather JPA managed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
@Value("#{abc.xyz == 'lmop'? true : false}")
```